# Getting App Groups for App Extensions to work

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-app-extension, app-id

I am following a tutorial [here](http://blog.intrepid.io/ios-app-extensions) in order to set up data sharing between my main App and my main App's App Extension.  Scrolling down a bit, they list 6 steps for the setup.  In step 3, I enable app groups in my Main App's target's capabilities.  I end up with the following:
[image: errors with app group capabilities]

I have tried "fix issue" and investigated my accounts under preferences but am frankly confused by this sort of thing. There appear to be one to zero threads about this on Stack and could not find any obvious answers searching google.  Has anybody dealt with this or something similar?